# Replace part of lines of a file that match a string in Bash

Tags: bash, sed

Here is what I'd like to do:

I have a file which is space delimited, and I have an array of integers. I need to search each line of the file (inv.txt) for each element in the array. If the pattern is found, I need to retain the first 7 characters of the line and replace the rest with "     0;     0;"

I'm very new to scripting and what I've tried so far is this: (I think I've gotten a little off track)

```
removing=(3199 26543)
for line in inv.txt
do
   for i in "${#removing[@]}"
   do
       sed -i "s/${removing[$1]/c\ ${line:0,7}      0;      0;/g inv.txt
   done
done
```

This gave me a sed -e expression #1 char 0: no previous regular expression
I doubt this is the best way to accomplish the task (if it even will)...Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm using an array because it will actually contain a couple thousand entries! The two I put in it for this scenario is just for testing.

Comment: Can you show a sample input and correspondent expected output?

Comment: Yes, here is two lines from the file I'm reading:
`100002; 20182;36205;36205; 640; 320201;   2000;     1;  1;`
`100003; 10273;26543;26543; 640; a60101;   2000;     1;  1;`

The second line has a match, at the end it should read:
`100003;     0;    0;    0;   0;      0;   8000;     0;   0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could actually do that with one sed (if it supports -r):

```
sed -rie '/3199|26543/s/^(.{7}).*/\1\t0;\t0;/' inv.txt
```

With the arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
removing=(3199 26543)
( IFS='|'; sed -rie "/${removing[*]}/s/^(.{7}).*/\\1\\t0;\\t0;/" inv.txt; )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it did not find/replace any of the lines in the file.

Comment: `-r` should actually be placed before `-i`. Please try again. Also, can you update your post with the output of `sed --version`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
removing=(3199 26543)
>output
while read line
do
   for i in "${removing[@]}"
   do
       if [[ "$line" =~  ^.*\ ${i}\  ]]; then
          echo "${line:0:7} 0; 0;" >> output
       else
          echo "$line" >> output    
       fi
   done
done < inv.txt

# you can uncomment below mv command if you want to overwrite inv.txt
# mv output inv.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  -i '/3199\|26543/s/^\(.\{7\}\).*/\1\t0\t0/' inv.txt
```